# Alternatives to the differential geometry part of PMA

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I have been doing well until I reached the chapter of differential geometry part of Rudin's Principle of Mathematical Analysis.

This is too tough to me. Can anyone recommend any alternatives? 
And I would like to ask what book on real analysis would be good to read after finishing Rudin.

Comment: PMA is called Baby Rudin so when you finish the baby, you might want to find his [dad](http://www.amazon.com/Complex-Analysis-Higher-Mathematics-Series/dp/0070542341).